# Getting "Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard'" while installing Sitecore 9.1

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I am trying to install Sitecore 9.1 in local environment but i am getting below issues while running the installation script. I have executed the Prerequisite.json too. Has anyone come across below issue when installing sitecore 9.1.

> [--------------------------------- XConnectXP0_CleanShards : Command
>   -------------------------------------------------] [ShardingTool - Clean]:[Path]
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xp91.xconnect\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Da
>   tabase.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe :  At
>   C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.0.0\Public\Tasks\Invoke-CommandTask.ps1:31
>   char:13
>   +             & $Path $Arguments | Out-Default
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   Unhandled Exception:   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.    at
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.Program.Main(String[]
>   args)
>
> Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Command
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xp91.xconnect\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Col
>   lection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe returned a non-zero
>   exit code - (255) At C:\installation\Sitecore
>   installers\Sitecore9.1\Setup\XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1:74 char:1
>   + Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Objec ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

Note: I have installed sitecore 9.0.2 earlier without any issues in local environment.

**Update1**
I'm able to resolve the above issue after installing the sp2. Earlier i have not restarted the machine after instaling the service pack2 that's why i have the above issue. Not it's resolved.

I'm getting below error when installation script is running. This happens when installation script tries to start IndexWorker service.

> Application: XConnectSearchIndexer.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
>   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(System.String,
>   System.String)    at
>   Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerAppDomainHost.CreateAppDomainAndIndexer()
>   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerAppDomainHost.Start()    at
>   Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.Service.OnStart(System.String[])
>   at
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(System.Object)
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[])
>   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.Program.RunAsService()    at
>   Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.Program.InitializeConfigurationAndRun(System.Action)
>   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.Program.Main(System.String[])
>
> Faulting application name: XConnectSearchIndexer.exe, version:
>   2.0.0.0, time stamp: 0xa35f4561 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.2608, time stamp: 0x5bd1340d Exception code:
>   0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x0000000000034048 Faulting process id: 0xb0c
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d48acc9f5bc6e9 Faulting
>   application path:
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xp91.xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\XConnectSearchIndexer.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   355d4902-db91-45e1-af6e-2dcc8072a915 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Which OS do you use? Can you run Windows Update and make sure that everything is up to date? Can you append your ps1 install script to your question?

Comment: Just out of curiosity do you have latest version of VS2017 on that machine? Check my blog post with installation instructions https://tothecore.sk/2018/11/28/sitecore-9-1-initial-release-installation-guide-for-development-machine/ . It went without any problem for me.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2016 ***SP2*** or SQL Server 2017?

Comment: Yes i installed SQL server 2016 update2 enterprise edition.

Comment: @PeterProcházka yes i have already installed vs 2017. i am following your post to install sitecore9.1

Comment: I installed sp2 but have not restarted my machine. now i'm not getting the above error.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this on machines that need a reboot following the running of the prerequisites.json.

The last task of prerequites.json should tell you if a reboot is required.

They are usually needed if any of the .net frameworks are installed, as they are only finalised when you reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t be mistaken for the "localhost" to automatically get the SQL instance.

[image]

Make sure you have [.Net Core SKD](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.1.500-windows-x64-installer) installed. (not sure, but it was supposed to done by the prerequisites)

> This may also occur when you are running another Server on your
>   machine like XAMPP server.